# How to get a union type from the properties of an object that implements interface with [key: string]?

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have this `interface` that I use to define a `PRODUCT_CATEGORIES` objec, where I keep the "source of truth" for all available product categories in my app. Each category is a string, which must have the language properties `EN | ES` and a `label` property for each language.

```
interface PRODUCT_CATEGORIES_TYPE {
  [key: string]: {
    [key in LANGUAGE]: {
      label: string
    }
  }
}
```

And this is the object where I initialize the `PRODUCT_CATEGORIES`

**CATEGORIES.ts**

```
export const PRODUCT_CATEGORIES: PRODUCT_CATEGORIES_TYPE = {
  category1: {
    EN: { label: "Label english" },
    ES: { label: "Label spanish" },
  },
  category2: {
    EN: { label: "Label english" },
    ES: { label: "Label spanish" },  
  },
  // AND SO ON...
};
```

I would like a way to get those category keys that were initialized in `PRODUCT_CATEGORIES` as a union (i.e: `category1 | category2`) so I can use in my `PRODUCT` interface.

EX:

```
interface PRODUCT {
  category: "category1" | "category2"
}
```

But I need that to be dynamically based on the categories initialized in `PRODUCT_CATEGORIES`.

I've tried this, but it does not work:

```
interface PRODUCT {
  category:   keyof typeof import("../constants/CATEGORIES").PRODUCT_CATEGORIES,
}
```

That just makes `category: string | number` and not `"category1" | "category2"`

**EXTRA THOUGHS**

I could also define a new type for that union, but it feels like duplicating a declaration that already exists in my JS run time code. Like:

Is this normal or is it a bad practice? I mean, the categories will be defined in the `PRODUCT_CATEGORIES` object, so that is the source of truth for those values in my app. Why would I need to "pre-declare" them into my types file?

```
type CATEGORY_VALUES = "category1" | "category2"

// THEN I COULD DO

type PRODUCT_CATEGORIES_TYPE {
  [key in CATEGORY_VALUES]: {
    [key in LANGUAGE]: {
      label: string
    }
  }
}

interface PRODUCT {
  category: BLOGPOST_CATEGORY_VALUES
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest to add a helper:

```
function defineProductCategories<T extends PRODUCT_CATEGORIES_TYPE>(data: T): T {
  return data
}
```

Now, use it:

```
export const PRODUCT_CATEGORIES = defineProductCategories({
  category1: {
    EN: { label: "Label english" },
    ES: { label: "Label spanish" },
  },
  category2: {
    EN: { label: "Label english" },
    ES: { label: "Label spanish" },  
  },
  // AND SO ON...
});
```

Then the keys of `PRODUCT_CATEGORIES` can be inferred:

```
interface PRODUCT {
  category: keyof typeof PRODUCT_CATEGORIES // "category1" | "category2"
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBAMgggOQOIFU5IKJQLxQEQYJ5QA++GAyngFDUCWAdsBAE4BmAhgMbQAKASgHkAIigDCAFQD6YuBIxJB-AJKUpEgJq8sAb2pQoAbQDWEEAC4oAZ2AtGAcwC6lvQYMmzURrESp0GZyhXNwMAGw4AIwhQyxs7Bnt9NwBfJNTU6ggADzAAexZgKC5chhsoARFxaVl5RRVKHCgAEwg2RgheFlymgFcuYDEOZnt8uggrAApgriGIEZYQAEYXJINCFyhwqJj8GEjoqAgE0LorAAtiZIAaVahKDa3oyzw97eswDgZTi6hrtJuDDNhvkQAAmFYhdZBTb7HYvWGHY7fS4Atz3aGPOGvA5WD5fc4ogz-JIAehJUEQwigFEEUEECAAdEzqMkAJQAblojGY7G4fCEokkQSSQLmIMsphAuTYUFAkGl5QFVRkcgUSlUFCgZPwovmS2IZDwupBoJoGTYPQY-ToJWarXanW6fQGs3mYysAB4JIcsswGE0rIrKpIVbV1WpNNoAHwTJpDDiWCSsxPCgwsCDAHosBjNeMsoA)

## Explanation

This instruction:

```
export const PRODUCT_CATEGORIES: PRODUCT_CATEGORIES_TYPE = { ... }
```

… is almost equivalent to:

```
export let PRODUCT_CATEGORIES: PRODUCT_CATEGORIES_TYPE;
PRODUCT_CATEGORIES = { ... };
```

… the type of `PRODUCT_CATEGORIES` is `PRODUCT_CATEGORIES_TYPE`, which is a keys/values dictionary.

If you want keep the keys in the type of `PRODUCT_CATEGORIES`, then you have to keep the original inferred type:

```
export const PRODUCT_CATEGORIES = { ... };
```

It works. But then you still need to check the typing of `PRODUCT_CATEGORIES`. The role of `defineProductCategories` is to keep the original type while performing the checking.

## DRY or not?

> I could also define a new type for that union, but it feels like duplicating a declaration that already exists in my JS run time code.

It is a matter of opinion. But an approach would be to ask: Where is the contract? You could decide that `CATEGORY_VALUES` is a contract here:

```
type CATEGORY_VALUES = "category1" | "category2"
```

… and then `PRODUCT_CATEGORIES` is an implementation.

But you could decide that `PRODUCT_CATEGORIES` *is* the contract as a constant for all your application. Then `CATEGORY_VALUES` could be inferred:

```
type CATEGORY_VALUES = keyof typeof PRODUCT_CATEGORIES;
```

… and the code is DRY.

The two versions are valid.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've added an extra though to my question. Could you take a look? Is it normal to do that pattern in Typescript? I mean, pre-defining property names that you are going to declare somewhere else?

Comment: @cbdeveloper I added a section.

Comment: Thanks a lot for these extra details. If I decide that `PRODUCT_CATEGORIES` **_is_** the contract as I was initially thinking of doing, then I'll need to implement the helper function that you've suggested, right? PS: Assuming I'm defining it as `[key: string]: {...}`. Otherwise I won't be able to infer the correct types for the keys.

Comment: Yes, exactly. But looking back I wonder if the content of `PRODUCT_CATEGORIES` should be in a JSON file and then you have to write `type CATEGORY_VALUES = "category1" | "category2"`.

Comment: Thanks again. I guess what makes more sense to me is: since `PRODUCT_CATEGORIES` is already implementing a contract for its nested properties, like `LANGUAGE`, it should also implement a contract for its top-level property, which will be `type CATEGORY_VALUES = "cat1" | "cat2"`. Typescript won't let me forget that and the implementation will always be in sync with the contract. The helper function should also work, but will hurt readability for me in the future. 3 months from now and that would feel like magic to me. Thanks a lot for you help!

Answer (score 0):

To get the full set of all possible keys and values in a union, use

```
type Intersect<T> =
    (T extends any ? (x: T) => any : never) extends
    (x: infer R) => any ? R : never
type ValueIntersectionByKeyUnion<T, TKey extends keyof Intersect<T> = keyof Intersect<T>> = T extends Record<TKey, any> ? ({
    [P in TKey]: T extends Record<P, any> ? (k: T[P]) => void : never
}[TKey] extends ((k: infer I) => void) ? I : never) : never;
type Usage = { [K in keyof Intersect<TA1>]: ValueIntersectionByKeyUnion<TA1, K> };
```